# I want AWS Spot pricing for a long-running job. Is a spot request of one instance the best way to achieve this?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a multi-day analysis problem that I am running on a 72 cpu c5n EC2 instance.  To get spot pricing, I made my code interruption-resilient and am launching a spot request of one instance.  It works great, but this seems like overkill given that Spot can handle thousands of instances.  Is this the correct way to solve my problem or am I using a sledgehammer to squash a fly?

I've tried normal EC2 launching, which works great, except that it is four times the price.  I don't know of any other way to approach this except for these two ways.  I thought about Fargate or containers or something, but I am running a 72 cpu c5n node, and those other options won't let me use that kind of horsepower (that I know of, hence my question).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Amazon EC2 Spot Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/) are an excellent way to get cheaper compute (up to 90% discount). The only downside is that the instances **might be stopped/terminated (your choice) if there is insufficient capacity**.

Some strategies to improve your chance of obtaining spot instances:

- Use instances **across different Instance Types and Availability Zones** because they each have different availability pools ([EC2 Spot Fleet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-fleet.html) can assist with this)
- Use resources on **weekends and in evenings** (even in different regions!) because these tend to be times of lower usage
- Use Spot Instances with a specified duration (also known as **Spot blocks**), but this is at a higher price and a maximum duration of 6 hours

If your software permits it, you could **split your load between multiple instances** to get the job done faster and to be more resilient against any stoppages of your Spot instances.

Hopefully your application is taking advantage of all the CPUs, otherwise you'd be better-off with smaller instances.

Comment: But is running a single instance a perfectly valid use case for EC2 spot?  Yes.